# Add attribute without value scalatags

Tags: scala, scala.js, scalatags

How to create attribute without value.

I want to create such (maybe not valid) html. Note `ng-app` and `ng-jq` - attributes without values.

```
<html ng-app ng-jq>
 ...
 ...
</html>
```

In scalatags you would start with:

```
import scalatags.JsDom.all._
html(
   //and here what?
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import scalatags.JsDom.all._
val `ng-app` = "ng-app".attr := ""  //empty string does the job
val `ng-jq` = "ng-jq".attr := ""

html(`ng-app`, `ng-jq`)
```

**update**

In scalatags-0.6.0 this becomes more explicit:

```
import scalatags.JsDom.all._
val `ng-app` = attr("ng-app") := ""  //empty string does the job
val `ng-jq` = attr("ng-jq") := ""

html(`ng-app`, `ng-jq`)
```